# Как передать фото в программу на c#

Tags: c#, скриншот

Установил недавно Snagit, делаю скриншоты. В нём есть много вариантов передачи скриншота в программы, например в ворд.
Как написать программу, что-бы в неё можно было передать картинку?
Вообщем хочу следующее(где просто экспорт в ворд не подойдёт):
лажу по инету...вдруг понравилось изображение- жму комбинацию клавишь-скриншот отправляется в программу и при этом в БД записуются ещё параметры (например тема, метки и др., которое я заранее создал).
В результате хотелось бы иметь следующее в базе: тема(метка,категория,примечание и т.д.) и файл встроенной картинки(в блоб поле ну или ссылку на файл)

Подскажите, как подобное сделать.
    Спасибо.

Comment: > лажу по инету  

----  

> записуются  

Я, конечно, не Grammar nazi, но пройти мимо не смог.

Answer (score 3):

Варианты:

- запускать программу с аргументами
     (путь к файлу скрина и теги),
     обрабатывать их (запись в базу) и
     сразу закрывать программу.
- программа
     постоянно висит в памяти, отслеживает
     комбинацию клавиш для снятия скрина,
     делает скрин, открывает диалоговое
     окно с предожением ввести теги и
     сохраняет скрин с тегами в базу.

Comment: Хотелось, что б я указал "такую-то" метку, а потом клацал снажитом, а он- передавал программе, которая будет в фоновом режиме запущена, и при этом каждый раз не отвлекаться. А потом зашёл - а там список фото с метками. Просто вот как это сделать.Я примеров не могу найти.